# how to remove attribute error in python

Tags: python

```
class dav():

    def d1():
        bit=1
        bit1=0

p1=dav()

print(p1.d1.bit)
```

The print statement raises an `AttributeError`:

```
AttributeError: 'function ' object has no attribute 'bit1'
```

Comment: Well, `bit` only exists while `d1()` is being called, which it isn't in your example. What is the actual problem you're trying solve with this code?

Comment: Are you trying to use a function like it's a class?

Answer (score 2):

```
class dav(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.bit=1
        self.bit1=0

p1=dav()

print(p1.bit)
```

is probably what you mean...